# AWS CI/CD with GItHub Actions and Code Deploy to the EC2 instance

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, github-actions, pm2, cicd

I am trying to do ci/cd with github actions and aws code deploy to the ec2 instance.

I have one ec2 instance and three github repositories(each repository has their own gitflow as well)

```
name: Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  buildAndTest:
    name: CI Pipeline
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ '14.x' ]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Initialize Node.js
      - name: Install Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      # Install project dependencies, test and build
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn
      - name: Run build
        run: yarn build

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: ['14.x']
        appname: ['app_name']
        deploy-group: ['group_name']
        region: ['region']

    needs: [buildAndTest]
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Initialize Node.js
      - name: Install Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      # Step 1
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ matrix.region }}
      # Step 2
      - name: Create CodeDeploy Deployment
        id: deploy
        run: |
          aws deploy create-deployment \
            --application-name ${{ matrix.appname }} \
            --deployment-group-name ${{ matrix.deploy-group }} \
            --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime \
            --github-location repository=${{ github.repository }},commitId=${{ github.sha }}
```

It works good when I push or do pull request to one repo, but when I push two repo at once which means I am gonna push and deploy concurrently, only one is success and another one is failed.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: .
    destination: /var/www/source

hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: deploy.sh // yarn install and restart server.
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

What is really curious is that except main location(in ec2), some files excluding build or so in other repos(two) are removed ???
I am using the same application and group id for three repositories and Is it a problem?

Any help would be super helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

AWS CodeDeploy application group can not make two deployments at the same time.